# Dropdown value is not binding in ngmodel using angular2

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript

I have dropdown using ng-model in angular2 and my view is not updating when I change the model

```js
 //intialize the variable
 addplanhours:any[];
 
 this.addplanhours=[{name: '--sel--',value:0}, {name: 'Head start',value:1}, {name: 'Nice going',value:2},{name: 'On Track',value:3},{name: 'Keep On trying',value:4},{name: 'Making process',value:5},{name: 'Wrapping up',value:6}];
 
 //function of electrifyonchange
 electrifyonChange(value) {
 for(var i=0;i<=this.addplanhours.length;i++){
   this.electrify= value;
   console.log("new value",this.electrify);
 }
```

```html
<span>
                  <span class="addnotefont1">Electrifying</span>
                  <select class="addplanpicker"[(ngModel)]="electrify" (ngModelChange)="electrifyonChange($event)">
               <option *ngFor="let a of addplanhours" [ngValue]="a.value">{{a.name}} </option>
          </select>
                </span>
```

Comment: It's a bit unclear (at least to me), as what's going on here. Where do you change the model and where in the view does it not reflect the change?

Comment: <option *ngFor="let a of addplanhours" [value]="a.value">{{a.name}} </option>
          </select>

Comment: Okay... I thought you would set `electrify` outside the *ngFor, apparently not,  but that brings then to my second question, where does it not update in your view?

Comment: its working fixed that

Answer (score 0):

`[ngValue]` can hold any kind of object or value, so you can use `[compareWith]` function to maintain the dropdown state because you are using object:

```
<select class="addplanpicker" [(ngModel)]="electrify" [compareWith]="isplanHourSelected"> 
    <option *ngFor="let a of addplanhours" [ngValue]="a">{{a.name}} </option>
</select>


isplanHourSelected(o1, o2) {
    return o1 && o2 && o1.value == o2.value
}
```

You will get `electrify` the selected object now, if you want to run a particular event when any value is selected in electrify then you can use [OnChange](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/OnChanges-interface.html) strategy.

Comment: Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'compareWith' since it isn't a known property of 'select'. ("t1">Electrifying</span>
                      <select class="addplanpicker" [(ngModel)]="electrify" [ERROR ->][compareWith]="isplanHourSelected">

Comment: `compareWith` is available in angular4 https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13268